# Using AutoHotkey to make CapsLock a Shift Lock for arrow keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

An AutoHotkey question.

In general, I would like to see, when `CapsLock` is on, pressing one `key` would produce `Shift` + `key`. My question is almost answered in a SuperUser question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1372196/solution-to-capslock-shift-every-key) and an AutoHotkey post [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/39645-using-caps-lock-status-to-toggle-shift).

With the help there, what I can achieve now is

1. when `CapsLock` is on, pressing `a` would produce `A`, and likewise for other letters;
2. when `CapsLock` is on, pressing `1` would produce `!`, `2` would produce `@`, and likewise for other keys with shifted symbols, e.g. `-` `=`;

**The special part of my question is that I want to see this behavior happen with arrow keys.**

To be specific:

3. when `CapsLock` is on, pressing `Right` arrow key would produce `Shift` + `Right`, and likewise for `Left`, `Up`, and `Down`;
4. when `CapsLock` is on, pressing `Ctrl` + `Right` would produce `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Right`;
5. In fact, I have remapped keys with `LAlt & L::Send {Right}` so that `Alt` + `L` would produce the `Right` arrow key. Now I want to see, when `CapsLock` is on,  `Alt` + `L` would produce `Shift` + `Right`.

For your information, I put a solution by Icarus from AutoHotkey forum here

```
#SingleInstance Force

Keys := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-=[];'\,./"
Loop parse, keys
    Hotkey $%A_LoopField%, PressKey

Return

PressKey:
    StringReplace ThisHotkey, A_ThisHotkey, $
    If( GetKeyState( "CAPSLOCK", "T" ) )
        SendInput +%ThisHotkey%
    Else
        SendInput %ThisHotkey%  

Return

ESC::ExitApp
```

It works for point 1 and point 2, but I do not know how to adapt it for arrow keys for points 3, 4 and 5. I tried appending `{Right}` to `Keys` in the above script but it won't work.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow managed to solve it myself. Excited!

The key is to **not** put `Right` in curly braces (like `{Right}`) when it stands on the left-hand side of `::` as the `originKey`.

Solutions corresponding to points 3 to 5 in my own question:

```
; Solution to Point 3
Left::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T")  ? "+{Left}"  : "{Left}"
Up::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T")    ? "+{Up}"    : "{Up}"
Down::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T")  ? "+{Down}"  : "{Down}"
Right::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T") ? "+{Right}" : "{Right}"

; Solution to Point 4
LCtrl & Left::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T")  ? "^+{Left}"  : "^{Left}"
LCtrl & Up::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T")    ? "^+{Up}"    : "^{Up}"
LCtrl & Down::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T")  ? "^+{Down}"  : "^{Down}"
LCtrl & Right::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T") ? "^+{Right}" : "^{Right}"

; Solution to Point 5
LAlt & J::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T") ? "+{Left}"  : "{Left}"
LAlt & I::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T") ? "+{Up}"    : "{Up}"
LAlt & K::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T") ? "+{Down}"  : "{Down}"
LAlt & L::SendInput % GetKeyState("CAPSLOCK", "T") ? "+{Right}" : "{Right}"
```

*There might be concise ways to write the above script, which is most welcome :)*

Answer (score 1):

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

/* 
; If your keyboard has no indicator for Caps Lock, you can use this GUI:
Gui, Capslock: -caption +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Capslock: Add, Text, x5 y5, Capslock is ON
If GetKeyState("Capslock","T")
    Gui, Capslock: Show, x0 y0
*/

Keys := ["Right","Left","Up","Down","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-","=","[","]",",","\",",",".","/",";"]
for each, key in Keys
    Hotkey, $%key%, Shift_Key
return

Shift_Key:
ThisHotkey := StrReplace(A_ThisHotkey, "$")
If GetKeyState("Capslock","T")
    SendInput, +{%ThisHotkey%}
else
    SendInput, {%ThisHotkey%}
return

/* 
~Capslock Up::
If GetKeyState("Capslock","T")
    Gui, Capslock: Show, x0 y0
else
    Gui, Capslock: cancel
return
*/
```

Comment: Thanks! I know very little about AHK's syntax. Do we have to write it like `"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"`, or can we write it like `"abcdefg"` and then somehow add `"Right"` to the list?

Comment: I'd reccomend to use [arrays](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm) (objects) instead of alternative methods. Arrays give you many features that other methods do not have.